# AWS EBS already consumed quite some space

Tags: amazon-web-services, storage, amazon-ebs

I'm a new aws joiner and on the free tier plan. what's confusing me is I don't store any user data on the EC2 instance but for some reason, 20% of the EBS were used (out of 30G). I want to avoid any unnecessary charge so want to figure out what is happening behind it.

1. What is consuming this storage? Is it the system files? Will it grow bigger?
2. Is there a way to view the content of the storage? I have tried the fleet manager, but it doesn't reflect the reality here (all showed files only consume some 20 MB).

Comment: Just ssh to the instance and check from inside what consumes your space.

Comment: Is it your boot disk? How did you "check from inside" how much space is being taken?

Comment: I used this command: df -h . and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, for the free tier we get 30GB is EBS storage. We can use this storage to attach it as drives to EC2 instances. The storage size for the volume attached to the instance is fixed. Although, you can increase the size of the EBS volume, this wont happen automatically. You wont encounter extra charges for storing data on those 30 GB.

> 1. What is consuming this storage? Is it the system files? Will it grow bigger?

Probably the operating system, update and preinstalled software depending on what OS are you using. If it will grow bigger or not, it depends on you, which updates do you install, what other software you are planning to install.

> Is there a way to view the content of the storage? I have tried the fleet manager, but it doesn't reflect the reality here (all showed files only consume some 20 MB).

Try connecting to the instance using either SSH/EC2 Instance Connect/System Manager/RDP and see what is consuming your disk space.